# How can I connect end vertices of two spiral curves?

Tags: vertices

I'm fairly new to Blender, using 2.8. I've tried several ways of drawing this spiral image, followed numerous tutorials on youtube that were close...but always something weird happens.

Regardless, if someone could let me know how to take two spirals I've created, (one just with a different radius), and connect the end vertices ultimately to create a face, then a 3D object. I've tried the connect vertices route, 'J' and 'F' to no avail.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble adding the low res gif without an error message, but it's basically an attempt to make a 3D swirl that can be modified in edit mode.

Comment: If you've made 2 different curve objects you need to join them with a ctrl J, then join the 2 vertices you want with F

Comment: ... and since the two individual curves weren't (I'm guessing) objects I used Convert From Curve to Mesh and then your suggestion worked. Thanks!